# How to go from a Pareto Distribution in Scipy to a Pareto Distribution in Mathematica?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, python

Assume that I have fitted a Pareto distribution via Scipy and have gotten the following parameters:

```
b = 1.543405484618  
loc = -1.292595471985
scale = 1.292605471984
```

How can I adjust these parameters to create a simulation in Mathematica?

NOTES:

1. `b` stands for the shape parameter
2. I tried these parameters in a `ParetoPickandsDistribution` expression
   to see if the mean from Scipy would match Mathematica's, but it did not.

Comment: You should give the value of the mean from Scipy otherwise you limit the number of folks who can help you.  Is the mean from Scipy 1.08612?  If so, then the *Mathematica* equivalent is `ParetoDistribution[scale,b,loc]`.

Comment: Did you check the SciPy documentation to see what definition they're using for the Pareto distribution?

Comment: Related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/449405/determining-shape-parameter-for-generalized-pareto-distribution-scipy.